# make AVPlayer fill the entire screen

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have an app where I'd like a video to play in the background of a single view.

What I did is create an `AVPlayer`, add that to an `AVPlayerLayer` and add that as a sublayer to my view.

Then I set the frame and the `videoGravity` property:

```
self.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
playerLayer.frame = self.bounds
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

Now the video plays, except it doesn't fill the entire screen. It fills it's original size, but it doesn't stretch/scale.

Am I missing something? Why is my video not resizing?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I added a screenshot and made the view purple for easier reference.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you post a screen shot for better understanding?

Comment: @andrehungaro Added

Comment: Where is this code placed? Try defining the playerLayer.frame inside viewDidLayoutSubviews(). I'm guessing that at the time you are defining the frames the final frames for the views were not yet calculated.

Comment: @andrehungaro Hero of the day! Could you make this into an answer so I could upvote & accept? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the playerLayer.frame inside viewDidLayoutSubviews()

At the time you are defining the frames the final frames for the views were not yet calculated.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to video to be stretch on the entire view, just delete the line

```
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

`videoGravity` default value is `AVLayerVideoGravityResize`

#### Update for Swift 5

```
playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: Looks like you set the layer frame not in the right place. debug it and make sure you have the right frame when you set it.