# Stretch AVPlayerLayer to fit into iPhone X format

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, video

I have an app where I play a video in the background in a certain view.

This video is always supposed to play fullscreen. I recently asked a question about stretching this video to fill up an iPhone plus model ([make AVPlayer fill the entire screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509972/make-avplayer-fill-the-entire-screen)) However, I just tested on an iPhone X, and the following happens:

[image]

I made the background of the view containing the `AVPlayerLayer` purple, just to clarify. As you can see, the video plays in the top of the screen (appx. 80pt), then there's the complete video, and then there's nothingness. How is this possible if my view does actually cover the entire screen?

This is how the video is made:

```
@objc fileprivate func playVideo() {
    log.debug("playVideo")
    let file = self.videoName.components(separatedBy: ".")

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file[0], ofType:file[1]) else {
        debugPrint( "\(file.joined(separator: ".")) not found")
        return
    }
    self.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    self.play()


    if (self.loop) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
            self.restart()
        }
    }

    self.backgroundColor = .purple

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(self.restart),
        name: Notification.Name("playVideos"),
        object: nil)
}
```

This method is called after `layoutSubviews()`.

How do I make the video stretch fully (with some overflow on the sides to make it visible of course)? Thanks :-).

Comment: That might happen if in the storyboard the view that contains the `AVPlayerLayer` is snapped to the Safe Area and not to the top of a superview.

Comment: @LëshaTurkowski The view is constrained to the actual `superview`, not to the `Safe Area`

Comment: You're also not setting `videoGravity` anywhere, default value is `.resizeAspect` which fits video into the frame instead of filling it (`.resizeAspectFill`). Might that be the case?